# For nested if, what will be the equivalent operation

Tags: rml

For the `if...else` statement below

```
if (a > b) {
    max = a;
}
else {
    max = b;
}
```

will result shortcut as below?

```
max = (a > b) ? a : b;
```

What about this `if` and `nested if` statement?

```
if (a > b) {
    max = a;
}
else {
    if (c > d)
        max = c;
    else
        max = d;
}
```

Comment: Could it be `max = (a > b) ? a : (c > d) ? c : d;`

Comment: The best way to find out would be to write some unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
max = (a > b) ? a :
      (c > d) ? c : d;
```

And this can be formatted to be arbitrarily long, so the formatting is important because ternary operators can get real confusing real fast. Consider:

```
max = (a > b) ? a :
      (b > c) ? b :
      (c ? d) ? c :
      (d ? e) ? d : e;
```

Verses:

```
max = (a > b) ? a : (b > c) ? b : (c ? d) ? c : (d ? e) ? d : e;
```